# How does obey robots.txt using Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I trying to crawl an entire website using Python2.7:

- I parsed robots.txt file using robotparser
- I open each link 'a' through the website, and
- I adds them to a list of pages to crawl
  The point is that:
  I tried to avoid all paths in Robots.txt file but they still in the list of pages to crawl.

How can I removed Robot.txt paths from my crawl list?

I coudn't find any help through stackoverflow yet.

my code bellow:

```html
import robotparser
import urlparse
import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *

AGENT_NAME = 'PYMOTW'
URL_BASE = 'website'
urls = [URL_BASE]
visited = [URL_BASE] # Create a copy
parser = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
parser.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(URL_BASE, 'robot.txt'))
parser.read()
PATHS = [
    '/..../',

    ]
for path in PATHS:
    print '%6s : %s' % (parser.can_fetch(AGENT_NAME, path), path)
    url = urlparse.urljoin(URL_BASE, path)
    print '%6s : %s' % (parser.can_fetch(AGENT_NAME, url), url)
    robot = [url]
while (len(urls) > 0 and robot != True):
    html = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # Parse All HTML using BeautifulSoup
    urls.pop(0)
# Retrieve all of Tags as a list
    for tags in soup.findAll('a', href = True):
        tags['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(URL_BASE, tags['href'])
        if URL_BASE in tags['href'] and tags['href'] not in visited:
            urls.append(tags['href'])
            visited.append(tags['href'])
        c = len(visited)
print visited
print 'page visited', c
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your post to remove the code snippet feature which is only for  HTML / JavaScript which runs in a web browser. I've also fixed spelling and  added formatting for readability in addition to removing Python 3 tag. Improving your question like this will increase your chances of people reading your question and getting good answers.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: Hi @J.F.Sebastian. The return is the list of True value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I corrected the code giving the url. I have the Disallow list but I'm not sure how to remove it from the list to crawl?

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear, you want to get the robot.txt and for every paths that you have predefined (in `PATHS`), you want to visit the page only if robot allows it ?

Comment: @Cyrbil - yes, exactly.

Comment: I can't visit the url in PATHS.

Comment: @Cyrbil ******  I have to achieve exactly the oposite ******  Your code is a bit unclear, you want to "get" the robot.txt and for every paths that you have predefined (in PATHS), you want to visit the page only if robot allows it ? *** I apologise about the confusion ***  I need to "Obey" Robot.txt file and crawled the rest of the website. My answer caused the oposite solution.

Comment: I will rewrite a bit my answer, but it is already what it does. PATHS is your web site entries, then we recursively crawl everything except if the path is not allowed in robots.txt

Comment: @Cyrbil - I been worked all day in this code without a positive result. The function read only PATHS - the paths not allow to fetch . 1) I tried to parsed the the '~martin/sewn/ls3' outside the function in line to crawl the pages but it is not possible 2) The function finish and print the page visited from PATHS 3) I tried to call a while loop and extract from the function the for loop but didn't work. I feel frustrated. Can I have some suggestion? please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several errors in your script.

I refactorize a lot and will try to explain.

1. First, you are using a loop when you want to do recursion (for every
   page that you get, you get links and redo the process).
2. Then for a reason I do not know, `urlparse.join` fails ... (your url is truncated), so I concat manually.
3. Beautiful soup is heavy, so I refactorize to only make it parse links and not the full page. A page can have relative and absolute links, so you need to handle both.
4. `robotparser` seems to be quite stupid, the path must be exact (`/test` and `/test/` are not the same for him). He also does not understand full url if they are not specified in the robots.txt (test for `http://example.com/test` matches `*/test` but not `/test` ...)
5. *Edit*: I made the script a bit more powerfull by filtering matched urls.

This give me:

```
import robotparser
import urlparse
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

AGENT_NAME = 'PYMOTW'
URL_BASE = 'http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/sewn/ls3'
DOMAIN = urlparse.urlparse(URL_BASE).hostname
visited = ['/']  # Create a copy

parser = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
parser.set_url(URL_BASE  + '/robots.txt')
parser.read()


def process_url(url):
    # transform relative paths
    parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if not parsed_path.hostname:
        url = URL_BASE  + url

    # check domain
    if parsed_path.hostname != DOMAIN:
        print 'External domain ignored: %s' % parsed_path.hostname

    # ensure we are allowed to fetch url
    if not parser.can_fetch(AGENT_NAME, parsed_path.path):
        print 'Not allowed to fetch %s' % parsed_path.path
        return

    # ensure we did not already visit it
    if url in visited:
        print 'Ignoring already visited %s' % url
        return

    print 'Visiting: %s' % url
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    visited.append(url)
    links = BeautifulSoup(html, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))

    # Retrieve all of Tags as a list
    for link in links:
        parsed_link = urlparse.urlparse(link['href'])
        if len(link['href']) is 0:
            print 'Ignoring empty link'
        elif link['href'][0] == '#':
            print 'Ignoring hash link %s' % link['href']
        elif parsed_path.hostname and parsed_link.scheme not in [None, 'http', 'https']:
            print 'Ignoring non http(s) links %s' % link['href']
        else:
            process_url(link['href'])

PATHS = [
    '/testpage.html',
    '/files/',
    '/images/',
    '/private/'
]
for path in PATHS:
    process_url(path)
```

Comment: I don't define functions yet. 
I'm a beginner so I tried to create a crawling program with my basic knowledges. Your corrections are very clear to me. 
I understand the recursions very well, even if they are inside a function (first time for me) however I have some questions:
- Why stack all the domain in the variable visited? can I work only for the domain /ls3/... ? 
- in def process_url(url) : Is not clear to me the variable: url = URL_BASE + url (url?) It is the parametre in the function called: process_url ?

Comment: You can filter to not crawl if outside of a domain. Put a new if condition before `print 'Visiting: %s' % url`. Also notice that this "bot" does not track on what domain it is on, and alwais prepend with the `URL_BASE` variable.  And yes, `url` is a parameter for the function `process_url`, but as it can be an absolute or relative path, I redefined it to always end up with an absolute url.

Comment: @Cyrbil If I'll insert a new condition before print 'Visiting: %s' %url the program will continue reading the robots not the Tags that I really need to crawl. To read my links I have to create a new function?, It is not clear to me. how can I crawl the page if I'm crawling the oposite section.  What exactly  does "bot" means?

Comment: @Cyrbil - Analising the program, It doesn't go into the function. Its crawling    '/testpage.html' from PATHS outside the loop.